# Install oauth for python3

Tags: python, development, oauth

I'm looking for easy way to install `python3-oauth` with pip.

I've found this
https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib

but it refers to python2.

I've found there are some packages for python3
https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-launchpadlib

but i need to build module that will install dependencies only from `setup.py`.

Is there any way to install lauchpadlib with oauth for python3 using pip?

Using python3
`pip3 install lauchpadlib && python3 -c 'import oauth.oauth'`

occurs in error in lib `oauth` `cannot import urlparse`

Comment: `python` and `python3` are different.  Have you considered trying `python3 -c ...` instead of `python`?  Because `python` refers to Python 2 and not Python 3.

Comment: Yes! Theres mistake in description. Should be `python3 -c ....`

Answer (score 1):

The `oauth` python module is outdated, deprecated, and unmaintained. You should use `python3-oauthlib` instead.

Comment: I dont need `python-oauth`. I need `launchpadlib`, but that has a dependency `python-oauth`. At pip `python-oauth` is available only for python2. Lauchpadlib is compatible with python3 and I need python3 oauth

Comment: Because python-oauth is unmaintained, the only reason there are python3-oauth packages in Debian/Ubuntu, is because there's a patch to add the necessary import changes for it to sort of work there. You can't apply patches when installing via pip/easy_install though. Really it would be best to file a bug against launchpadlib upstream, about how it's using a deprecated oauth lib. Migrating it to oauthlib should be pretty easy though.

Comment: There is a confirmed bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/lazr.restfulclient/+bug/1672458

Answer (score 0):

As of lazr.restfulclient 0.14.0 (released on 2018-05-08), the launchpadlib stack uses `oauthlib` rather than `oauth`.  If you have code that needs to do unusual things directly with the underlying OAuth library to integrate with launchpadlib, then perhaps the example of [https://code.launchpad.net/~cjwatson/lazr.restfulclient/oauthlib/+merge/344716](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ecjwatson/lazr.restfulclient/oauthlib/+merge/344716) will help you port your code.